# Need advice on how to setup a Drupal site on a given scenario

Tags: entities, views

I need ideas/help on how to setup a drupal website with following given scenario. I just come up with the scenario this is not real but if I get the answers then I think I can apply on real poject.

I have two content-type **Movies** & **Celebrities**.

Movies content type will list all the movies information like...
"Movie story overview", "movie review" and "movie cast"

Similarly I have Celebrities content type which will Celeb information like
Movies acted, Bio, awards etc.

Now what I want...

**First Objective:**

- When I add a new celebrities node to site, how can I create/add multiple pages automatically
  Example: I added a new celebrity named “kate winslet” by using “Add Content”->Celebrities content type. Now when I save it there should be 4 urls created in one go.

  a.   Domain.com/celebrity/kate-winslet
     b.   Domain.com/celebrity/kate-winslet /movies-acted
     c.   Domain.com/celebrity/kate-winslet /bio
     d.   Domain.com/celebrity/kate-winslet /awards

Similarly while adding a Movies content type it should generate multiple pages like

- a.   Domain.com/movies/titanic/overview
- b.  Domain.com/movies/titanic/cast
- c. And more like this.

Note: I don’t want to create pages manually. Only one main landing page for each type should be created manually and rest of the pages should be added itself.

Now...

**Second Objective:**

- On the “domain.com/movies/titanic/cast” page, how can I have functionality to look-up all the celebrities page titles & url and link both, a movie with its casts or an actor/actress with movies.

**Example:** I added a new movie “titanic”, now the movies content type may have a custom filed (CCK) named as “movie cast” where I will be adding actor/actress full name like “kate winslet”, “leonardo dicaprio” etc.

Now what I want is these names should be link to their corresponding celebrity pages like

a.  “kate winslet” shoule be linked to Domain.com/celebrity/kate-winslet

b.  And “leonardo dicaprio” should be linked to Domain.com/celebrity/ Leonardo-dicaprio

Any idea or help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is multiple questions, really, but here's a quick answer for you:

Part 1: Using Views, you can accomplish having multiple "pages" for a given node. You'll have all the data for those pages on the one "kate-winslet" node. Then you'll create a view that takes an argument from the URL. The path of the view will be entered something like this:
/celebrity/%1/movies-acted. You will need to add the fields you want to each view or view display. Then you'll add a contextual filter, using the node id. If this doesn't make sense to you, you just need to learn how to use Views, and particularly how to use contextual filters in Views.

Part 2: Yeah, you just need to view a tutorial on how to use Views. This is a simple View, but you'll need to use the views_attach module, too probably.